# Android App Button 'onClick'

Tags: android, button, buttonclick

I am creating a charity app for Android. The app consists of 4 pages, each with a button which, when clicked, should navigate the user to the next page.

-Currently using Eclipse SDK-

The first (welcome) page button works and the code for this is:

```
public class CharityAppActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

Button main = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
main.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
setContentView(R.layout.donate);
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

});

}
```

I am wondering where I should put the code for the other buttons? 
(this java file is currently called CharityAppActivity.java)....

Any help would be gratefully received. I would be more than willing to offer you any more code if you need it to help me a little better

Ps. the pages are named main.xml, donate.xml, value.xml and thanks.xml

Answer (score 1):

Activity is only one screen of application.

You should create more activities for every screen and do not try to only change content. It is not possible call setContentView() multiple times by default.

I suggest you try to more samples application from SDK directly, read some tutorials or book.

Comment: Create 4 Activities, let each Button call http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29 for the next activity and that's it.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering whether i would need to do that (although i am  new so i struggle to trust my own judgements). I should just create a new activity for every button and call that using id?

Answer (score 0):

Like you are finding  Button main = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
find other buttons from your main activity and set their onClickHandler to invoke your different activities.

I am assuming all the four concerned buttons are in same layout.

Comment: generally I have 4 windows (terminology may be wrong) and each of these four windows has a button to allow the user to navigate to the next logical window. The code above works perfectly to go from the main window to the donate window onClick. I wonder where in the above class can i place code to handle all other buttons seperately.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create 4 Activities.

The OnClick method will call the next Activity using "**startActivity**"

@Override

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent it = new Intent(NextClass.class);
    startActivity(it);

}
```